# How to replace a word inside a .DOCX file using Linux command line?

Tags: linux, text-processing, microsoft-word

I want to change a word in a .docx file using a shell command.
I tried using the `sed` command, but it is not working.
Does anyone know a solution for this?

For example, I want to change a word (e.g. `exp5`) and replace that with another (`exp3`) in the file `exo.docx`.

Comment: sorry , exp5 with exp3

Comment: You can edit your questions.

Comment: `.docx` is actually a zip format archive. Extract the `word/document.xml` file from it, apply the sed to it, and add it back to the archive. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats) has more information on the format.

Comment: check here as well... http://askubuntu.com/questions/364872/how-to-view-a-doc-from-command-line

Comment: Why can't you use an appropriate tool like OpenOffice?

Comment: @Dmitry there are lots of valid reasons that would take us far off topic. I'm sure google will help you

Comment: @DarrenH I didn't ask for "lots of valid reasons", just for the reason the OP had.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So, you want to replace things in a brand-specific format? At the first look it looks bad, but the new `docx` format is a bit better for that than the old `doc` format, because it's actually a ZIP file containing `XML` files.

So the answer lies in unzipping it, then you'll have to rummage through the files and figure out on which one to call `sed` and zip it up again.

Check out the file `word/document.xml` in the ZIP file.

Comment: a side note: "mc" (midnight commande) is able to open & go "inside" the directories and files of a zip file, seamlessly. You should be able to start mc (mc) , then navigate to the file, Enter on it to "enter" its content, then find the relevant file you need to change, edit it (F3, if my memory is correct? the menu should be at the bottom of your screen) save it, and exit (navigate up until you "exit" the .zip file) : it will ask if you want to save the modifications. For this to work you may have to tell "mc" to handle .docx and .xlsx files as zip files, though

Comment: I have nightmares about `sed` on XML....

Comment: @cat [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), I assume

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Yes, rather like that, although `sed` can describe non-regular grammars, right? So maybe it's not quite so bad (but use a parser!)

Comment: Replacing a single word should probably be ok, if it doesn't occur as a tag name, but in general, using regex on xml is inappropriate and incorrect from the grammar point of view. I don't know what OP wants - if it needs to be an automatic script, then using a file manager and text editor is out of a question.

Answer (score 5):

try this script:

```
FILE=$1    
RETPATH=`pwd`    
rm -rf /var/tmp/docx    
mkdir /var/tmp/docx    
cp $FILE /var/tmp/docx
cd /var/tmp/docx    
mkdir tmp
unzip $FILE -d tmp
cd tmp/word
sed -i "s/${2}/${3}/" document.xml
cd ..
zip -r ../${FILE} *
cp /var/tmp/docx/${FILE} ${RETPATH}
cd $RETPATH
rm -rf /var/tmp/docx
```

and call the script as follows:

```
./repdocx FILE_NAME OLD_STRING NEW_STRING
```

Comment: If using OSX don't forget to add sed -i ''

Comment: Good answer. Now how about multiple docx file?

Answer (score 2):

Modifying and cleaning up [schraubenkarl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/218084/schraubenkarl)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347715/80216) (must be in the directory of the docx):

```
find_and_replace() {
    FILE=$1
    FIND=$2
    REPLACE=$3

    unzip "$FILE" -d tmp #unzip
    sed -i '' -e "s/$FIND/$REPLACE/g" tmp/word/document.xml #find/replace
    cd tmp && zip -r ../"$FILE" * && cd .. #zip
    rm -rf tmp
}
```